# How to reference bootstrap.css in Yii2?

Tags: css, dynamic, twitter-bootstrap-3, directory, yii2

I would like to use the bootstrap.css file as a reference in a HTML2PDF extension as I rely heavily on it when building a table - which I need to export into a PDF as well.

So my goal would be to include the CSS file link in the HTML that I compile, but I do not know how to reference the CSS file properly. Obviously, I can look up what the browser loads, such as: `http://sitename/web/assets/e2eb51c9/css/bootstrap.css` but this - I suspect - is not a permanent link, that alphanumeric folder name might be re-generated upon update or something?

So I'm looking for an alias of some-sort much like the `@webroot` works for looking up the `web` folder. I'm **imagining** it might look something like: `Yii::$app->vendors("bootstrap")->getFolder()`.

**Is** there a function like this?

Comment: Reade about assets in the yii2 docs

Comment: @Sfili_81 thanks to your tip, I dug deeper into the topic and came up with something. Will you let me know if this is an optimal approach, please? (It'll be up in a moment as an answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I've included the following in the HTML HEAD:

```
$bs = new \yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset;
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='" . str_replace('\\', '/', $bs->sourcePath) . '/' . $bs->css[0] . "'>
```

It does work, I'm just not sure this is an elegant way to achieve it.

Comment: There is another way of doing this [Link](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/structure-assets#customizing-asset-bundles)

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of ways to do that:

**1)** Use asset bundles. It's not necessarily to place it in `AppAsset` bundle. By default it's common bundle and included in main layout so all included assets will be published in every view.

You can create your own AssetBundle.

Note that for external assets (that are outside web accessible directory) you need to use `sourcePath`, otherwise - `basePath` and `baseUrl` properties.

With both options all you have to do in common case - fill `$js` and `$css` arrays and `$depends` for setting dependencies if it's needed.

You can read more by the link below.

**2)** Use `registerCssFile()` and `registerJsFile()`.

First approach is preferable and recommended in official docs. It gives you dependencies handling and much more.

**Official docs:**

- [Assets](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-assets.html)
- [yii\web\AssetBundle](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-assetbundle.html)
- [yii\web\View registerCssFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerCssFile%28%29-detail)
- [yii\web\View registerJsFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-view.html#registerJsFile%28%29-detail)